# How to keep the size of second column of a QtreeWidget (with more than 2 columns) dynamic?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I have a mainwindow with Qtreewidget(having 3 columns) as central widget. I want to keep the size of first and second column fixed, but the size of second column should be equal to the size of qtreewidget minus the size of other two columns. Since the size of mainwindow (also, treewidget) can be changed, how to keep the second column size changing as well?

Comment: Do you want to expend the last column? something like this `tw->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `header()`funtion of `QTreeWidget`, you can get the `QHeaderView` object.

In the document link(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#sizeHintForColumn),  you notice that

> If you need to set the width of a given column to a fixed value, call
>   QHeaderView::resizeSection() on the view's header.

```
void QHeaderView::resizeSection(int logicalIndex, int size)
```

So the rough code could be:

```
QHeaderView* headerView = treeWidget->header();
headerView->resizeSection(COLUMN_INDEX, FIXEDSIZE); //Calculate the required size and do this for required columns.
```